# expand and change images on hover within a 3 image panel section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a 3 panel image section (section 1, 2 and 3) - on hover over section 1 for example, I would like for the original bg to fade out while a new bg fades in while simultaneously growing to the full length of the section "overlapping" the other sections. Once this section is full width I would like to be able to hover over section two and the same process occur without having to actually move the mouse out of the section area first.

I have managed to get to a point where the section expands and the image changes over, however, once say section 1 is expanded - it occupies the full width of the section so hovering over section 2 does not trigger the hover animation for section 2. Instead I have to move the mouse so that it is outside of the section and re-enter over section 2 to begin that animation.

Its probably easier to see so attached is a jsfiddle in addition to the code below.

https://jsfiddle.net/tr5km94w/1/

```
<div class="panel-test-background">
  <div class="panel-test-one"></div>
  <div class="panel-test-two"></div>
  <div class="panel-test-three"></div>
</div>

<div class="panel-container">
  <div class="panel-one">
    <div class="panel-text-one">
      <div class="text-top">
          <h3>section</h3>
          <br />
          <h1>Section Title No.01</h1>
          <br />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-two">
    <div class="panel-text-two">
        <div class="text-top">
            <h3>section</h3>
            <br />
            <h1>Section Title No.02</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-three">
    <div class="panel-text-three">
        <div class="text-top">
            <h3>section</h3>
            <br />
            <h1>Section Title No.03</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>

<style>
.panel-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 75vh;
    display: flex;
}

.panel-one {
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 75vh;
    position: relative;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.panel-two {
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 75vh;
    position: relative;
    pointer-events: none;
    left: 6px;
 }

.panel-three {
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 75vh;
    position: relative;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.panel-text-one {
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 75vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 3rem;
    pointer-events: none;
}


.panel-text-two {
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 75vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 3rem;
    pointer-events: none;
 }

.panel-text-three {
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 75vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 3rem;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.panel-text-one h3 {
    font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: white;
}

.panel-text-one h1 {
    font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: white;
}

.panel-text-one span {
    color: white;
}

.panel-text-two h3 {
    font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: white;
}

.panel-text-two h1 {
    font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: white;
}

.panel-text-two span {
    color: white;
}

.panel-text-three h3 {
    font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: white;
}

.panel-text-three h1 {
    font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: white;
}

.panel-text-three span {
    color: white;
}

.panel-test-background {
    width: 100%;
    height: 75vh;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
}

.panel-test-one {
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 75vh;
    background: red;
    width: 0%;
    transition: width 0.5s;
}

.panel-test-one:hover {
    width: 100%;
    transition: width 0.5s;
    background: blue;
}

.panel-test-two {
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 75vh;
    background: green;
    width: 0%;
    transition: width 0.5s;
}

.panel-test-two:hover {
    width: 100%;
    transition: width 0.5s;
    background: yellow;
}

.panel-test-three {
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 75vh;
    background: purple;
    width: 0%;
    transition: width 0.5s;
}

.panel-test-three:hover {
    width: 100%;
    transition: width 0.5s;
    background: pink;
}
</style>
```

The issue I am having then I guess is that because whichever section you initially hover over takes up the full width of the container so that when section 1 is expanded, although I am hovered over section 2 or 3 it is still technically section 1 since it is full-width. Is there anyway around this so that I can trigger the other animations when I hover over the respective sections? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

edit: for a bit of clarification of what an ideal end would like look, I was inspired by the image section on basicagency.com near the end of the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I did notice is that with the initial  it appears that there are only 3 's and there should be 4 's before the next section begins.  This may be helpful to try.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, is there anyway you can elaborate a little more? I am not sure if I am following what you mean.